# Memoryless property: how does $P(X > s + t \mid X > s) = P(X > t), s, t \ge 0$ imply that $F^c(s + t) = F^c(s) F^c(t), s, t \ge 0$?

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am currently studying the textbook *Modeling and analysis of stochastic systems*, third edition, by Kulkarni. Chapter **5.1.1 Memoryless Property** says the following:

> We begin with the definition of the memoryless property.
>
> **Definition 5.2** *A non-negative random variable $X$ is said to have the memoryless property if*
> $$P(X > s + t \mid X > s) = P(X > t), \ \ \ \ \ s, t \ge 0. \tag{5.3}$$

> **Theorem 5.1 Memoryless Property.** *A continuous non-negative random variable has memoryless property if and only if it is an $\exp(\lambda)$ random variable for some $\lambda > 0$.*
>
> **Proof:** We first show the "if" part. So suppose $X \sim \exp(\lambda)$ for some $\lambda > 0$. Then,
> $$\begin{align} P(X > s + t \mid X > s) &= \dfrac{P(X > s + t, X > s)}{P(X > s)} \\ &= \dfrac{P(X > s + t)}{P(X > s)} = \dfrac{e^{-\lambda(s + t)}}{e^{-\lambda s}} \\ &= e^{-\lambda t} = P(X > t). \end{align}$$
> Hence, by definition, $X$ has memoryless property. Next we show the "only if" part. So, let $X$ be a non-negative random variable with complementary cdf
> $$F^c(x) = P(X > x), \ \ \ \ x \ge 0.$$
> Then, from Equation 5.3, we must have
> $$F^c(s + t) = F^c(s) F^c(t), \ \ \ \ s, t \ge 0.$$

How does Equation 5.3 imply that $F^c(s + t) = F^c(s) F^c(t), s, t \ge 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$P(X > s+t \mid X > s) =  \frac{P(X > s+t, X > s)}{P(X > s)} = \frac{P(X > s+t)}{P(X > s)} = \frac{F^c(s+t)}{F^c(s)}$$
and
$$P(X > t) = F^c(t).$$

Comment: So how does this get us to $F^c(s + t) = F^c(s) F^c(t), s, t \ge 0$? Maybe I'm missing something, but the last fact $P(X > t) = F^c(t)$ seems redundant after already showing that $P(X > s+t \mid X > s) =  \dfrac{P(X > s+t, X > s)}{P(X > s)} = \dfrac{P(X > s+t)}{P(X > s)} = \dfrac{F^c(s+t)}{F^c(s)}$, no?

Comment: @ThePointer Your question was "how does (5.3) imply $F^c(s+t) = F^c(s) F^c(t)$?" I have shown that the left-hand side of (5.3) is $F^c(s+t)/F^c(s)$ and the right-hand side of (5.3) is $F^c(t)$, so (5.3) can be rewritten as $F^c(s+t) = F^c(s) F^c(t)$.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, I confused myself.